# Other user's profile is not showing, It is showing only current user name . How to display other user's profile?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am creating a web app and I want this to display  other user's profile through the user's post.
I mean when a user click on other user's profile for see the other user's information then it will show the other user's profile. I've tried everything but it is showing the name of the current user information after click on the post.

Please Help me in this. Thank you very Much. I will really apppreciate your Help.

Here is my Code:-

views.py

```
def post_profile(request,username):
    poste = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    context = {'poste':poste}
    return render(request, 'mains/post_profile.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Please help me in this, I don't know where is the problem

Comment: In your ```def post_profile``` you are using ```user = request.user```. Since the current user is requesting to view other people's profile, the profile of current user will be shown.

Comment: but what should i use instead of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Create a profile url and pass the `user_id` parameter with it.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns =[
    ....
    path('profile/<int:user_id>', views.show_profile, name='show_profile'),
]
```

Now create a view and pass the `user_id` parameter with the `request` parameter to it.

```
def show_profile(request, user_id):
    poste = Profile.objects.get(user=user_id)
    context = {'poste': poste}
    return render(request, 'mains/post_profile.html', context)
```

Now show the user profile in the template.

Comment: Dear sir, it is showing the error - Reverse for 'show_profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)$']

sir can you tell your email, so i can talk to you there, i will show all the code there

Comment: Okay, it's `lingayatajay2810@gmail.com`.